# how to do image textclean by imageMagic(textcleaner) by python program

Tags: image, python-2.7, imagemagick

I am trying to pre-process an image so as to improve accuracy when using tesseract. To help with that, how can I apply the ImageMagick bash shell script, textcleaner, programatically via Python.

Comment: Fred's `textcleaner` script is a bash utility. Use python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: please may you give the model code for this process

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098012/how-to-run-image-magick-textcleaner-commands-on-spyder-in-python/51106381#51106381

Comment: you can find example how to use text cleaner on this site
https://github.com/youssriaboelseod/table-parser-opencv

but i still have problem when i execute this file py python

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the script of textcleaner from - http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php and place the same in the folder in which you are writing your python script
2. bashCommand = "sh textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20 input_file.format output_file.format"
   Create a bash command to run the textcleaner for processing the image. Tweek the parameters to get a better processed image.
3. import subprocess
   process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, error = process.communicate()
   Run this code to get the processed image.