# how to run image magick textcleaner commands on spyder in python

Tags: python, imagemagick

I am trying to run the Imagemagick bash shell script, textcleaner, from Spyder IDE with the following syntax, but I was not able to get it to work.

import os 
os.system("textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 30 -o 12 -s 2 in.png out.png")

Answer (score 0):

Textcleaner is my Imagemagick bash shell script. I have not tried to run it from Python. But this should work using Python 3 subprocess.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 30 -o 12 -s 2 in.png out.png'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

You may need to preface textcleaner with bash and/or the full path to textcleaner. Also you may need to provide the full paths to the input and output. Also be sure to edit the script's permissions to make it executable (chmod u+x textcleaner). See my Pointers for Use at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I installed ImageMagick in my system.I am not able to install textcleaner on my system.How can i install it and give its complete path.

Comment: Are you on a Unix system or Windows. My scripts do not work in Windows. They need a Unix system. Do you have Python 2 or 3? I am not sure subprocess.call works for Python 2, but I am not a Python expert. If you are on Unix, then just download my script. It is just a text file. Put the full path to the script in the cmd. You may have to preface with bash as well. Be sure that Imagemagick convert is in your Unix PATH variable. What version of Imagemagick did you install? See my Pointers for use on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. Sorry I know nothing about spyder

Comment: I am running this on Windows. Is there any way to run bash script on Windows?

Comment: You can run a bash script in Window 10, if using the built in Unix system or if you install Cygwin. Basically bash does not run in native Windows and needs a Unix-like system. So you would need to install Python in the Unix Windows system rather than in the native Windows. In native Windows with Imagemagick installed, you can get something like my textcleaner, by `convert input -negate -lat 25x25+10% -negate output`. Vary the arguments as needed.